# Using IBM Watson Assistant - there is no spell check option for languages other than English. Why?

Tags: cloud, websphere, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I was looking for the autocorrection section in Option, but there is nothing.
I'm using Watson Assistant in Italian, and I suppose there is no spell check option in this language. Am I correct?
Why does IBM say it supports more languages, if spell check is not supported?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by spell check. Are you referring to fuzzy entity matching?

Comment: No, I mean spell check, or auto correction. In Watson's "Try it" dialog, when your input has grammatical errors, it automatically corrects to a typo-free input

Comment: The "Try it" panel will be a web based text editor with the auto-correct feature, and not directly related to the Watson Assistant service.